# Apache Ignite Near Cache - local cache metrics

Tags: ignite

I've been experimenting with Ignite Near Caches.  In doing so I'm configuring a client node with two server nodes in the cluster.  I instantiated a near cache and would like to see the associated metrics on the cache hits/misses.  Functionally everything works fine, but I can't figure out where the near cache metrics are.

I've tried to extract the cache metrics via calls

```
NearCacheConfiguration<Integer, Integer> nearCfg = 
    new NearCacheConfiguration<>();

nearCfg.setNearEvictionPolicyFactory(new LruEvictionPolicyFactory<>(100));
nearCfg.setNearStartSize(50);

IgniteCache<Integer, Integer> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(
    new CacheConfiguration<Integer, Integer>("myCache"), nearCfg);
// run some cache puts and gets
for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) { cache.put(i, i); }
for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) { cache.get(i); }

// then try to retrieve metrics
System.out.println(cache.localMetrics());
System.out.println(cache.metrics());
```

output

```
CacheMetricsSnapshot [reads=0, puts=0, hits=0, misses=0, txCommits=0, txRollbacks=0, evicts=0, removes=0, putAvgTimeNanos=0.0, getAvgTimeNanos=0.0, rmvAvgTimeNanos=0.0, commitAvgTimeNanos=0.0, rollbackAvgTimeNanos=0.0, cacheName=myCache, offHeapGets=0, offHeapPuts=0, offHeapRemoves=0, offHeapEvicts=0, offHeapHits=0, offHeapMisses=0, offHeapEntriesCnt=0, heapEntriesCnt=0, offHeapPrimaryEntriesCnt=0, offHeapBackupEntriesCnt=0, offHeapAllocatedSize=0, size=0, keySize=0, isEmpty=true, dhtEvictQueueCurrSize=0, txThreadMapSize=0, txXidMapSize=0, txCommitQueueSize=0, txPrepareQueueSize=0, txStartVerCountsSize=0, txCommittedVersionsSize=0, txRolledbackVersionsSize=0, txDhtThreadMapSize=0, txDhtXidMapSize=0, txDhtCommitQueueSize=0, txDhtPrepareQueueSize=0, txDhtStartVerCountsSize=0, txDhtCommittedVersionsSize=0, txDhtRolledbackVersionsSize=0, isWriteBehindEnabled=false, writeBehindFlushSize=-1, writeBehindFlushThreadCnt=-1, writeBehindFlushFreq=-1, writeBehindStoreBatchSize=-1, writeBehindTotalCriticalOverflowCnt=0, writeBehindCriticalOverflowCnt=0, writeBehindErrorRetryCnt=0, writeBehindBufSize=-1, totalPartitionsCnt=0, rebalancingPartitionsCnt=0, keysToRebalanceLeft=0, rebalancingKeysRate=0, rebalancingBytesRate=0, rebalanceStartTime=0, rebalanceFinishTime=0, keyType=java.lang.Object, valType=java.lang.Object, isStoreByVal=true, isStatisticsEnabled=false, isManagementEnabled=false, isReadThrough=false, isWriteThrough=false, isValidForReading=true, isValidForWriting=true]
CacheMetricsSnapshot [reads=0, puts=0, hits=0, misses=0, txCommits=0, txRollbacks=0, evicts=0, removes=0, putAvgTimeNanos=0.0, getAvgTimeNanos=0.0, rmvAvgTimeNanos=0.0, commitAvgTimeNanos=0.0, rollbackAvgTimeNanos=0.0, cacheName=myCache, offHeapGets=0, offHeapPuts=0, offHeapRemoves=0, offHeapEvicts=0, offHeapHits=0, offHeapMisses=0, offHeapEntriesCnt=0, heapEntriesCnt=100, offHeapPrimaryEntriesCnt=0, offHeapBackupEntriesCnt=0, offHeapAllocatedSize=0, size=0, keySize=0, isEmpty=true, dhtEvictQueueCurrSize=-1, txThreadMapSize=0, txXidMapSize=0, txCommitQueueSize=0, txPrepareQueueSize=0, txStartVerCountsSize=0, txCommittedVersionsSize=0, txRolledbackVersionsSize=0, txDhtThreadMapSize=0, txDhtXidMapSize=-1, txDhtCommitQueueSize=0, txDhtPrepareQueueSize=0, txDhtStartVerCountsSize=0, txDhtCommittedVersionsSize=-1, txDhtRolledbackVersionsSize=-1, isWriteBehindEnabled=false, writeBehindFlushSize=-1, writeBehindFlushThreadCnt=-1, writeBehindFlushFreq=-1, writeBehindStoreBatchSize=-1, writeBehindTotalCriticalOverflowCnt=-1, writeBehindCriticalOverflowCnt=-1, writeBehindErrorRetryCnt=-1, writeBehindBufSize=-1, totalPartitionsCnt=0, rebalancingPartitionsCnt=0, keysToRebalanceLeft=0, rebalancingKeysRate=0, rebalancingBytesRate=0, rebalanceStartTime=-1, rebalanceFinishTime=-1, keyType=java.lang.Object, valType=java.lang.Object, isStoreByVal=true, isStatisticsEnabled=false, isManagementEnabled=false, isReadThrough=false, isWriteThrough=false, isValidForReading=true, isValidForWriting=true]
```

Looks like there are no meaningful metrics.  I figured that it may be part of the NearCacheConfiguration to configure stats as is the case with CacheConfiguration but no.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.  I missed the CacheConfiguration passed into the igniteCache object.

code snippet is:

```
CacheConfiguration<Integer, Integer> cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<Integer, Integer>("myCache");
cacheConfiguration.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
IgniteCache<Integer, Integer> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfiguration, nearCfg);
```

after all the cache operations are run I see the statistics now.